# Creating a for loop to calculate all the terms for pi

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I'm trying to work out how to create some code to calculate pi. My goal for the first function is to calculate each term based on the equation. The major issue for the first function is that it only returns a single value rather than a list of values. It seems like it isn't even running the for loop. The code below would ideally return a list of all the terms for n =  0 - 100 but it's not.

```
def term_in_series_1(n):
    for k in range (n, -1,-1): 
        value_of_term_n = 2 * 2**k * (factorial(k))**2 / factorial(2*k+1)  
    return value_of_term_n

term_in_series_1(100)
```

For example, I want to achieve what the below code does but by creating a function:

```
N = 100

for k in range (N, -1,-1):
    value_of_term_n = 2 * 2**k * (factorial(k))**2 / factorial(2*k+1) # This is the argument that 

    print(value_of_term_n)
```

Thanks in advance for any help (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a list in the function and appending the values will have the same effect as printing for each loop

```
def term_in_series_1(n):
    values=[]
    for k in range (n, -1,-1): 
        value_of_term_n = 2 * 2**k * (factorial(k))**2 / factorial(2*k+1) 
        values.append(value_of_term_n)
    return values

term_in_series_1(100)
```